# How to Create Responsive Side by Side Sections in HTML and CSS Only

Tags: html, css

I want to create a box for pros and cons just like Life Hacker which looks like this:

[image]

As a beginner in HTML CSS, I started and so far, I have this:

[image]

As can see there is too much overlapping. How do I fix this? Also, I would like to align the text with the list.

HTML:

```css
.indent-1 {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.indent-1 section {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="indent-1">
  <section>
    <h3>What we like:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Pro 1</li>
      <li>Pro 2</li>
      <li>Pro 3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>What we don't like:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Con 1</li>
      <li>Con 2</li>
      <li>Con 3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</section>
```

Any more suggestions to make it look pretty will be welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use floated elemets, try to start use flexbox or grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid is the way to go here as you can use the grid-template-columns to set the width equally. Flexbox will do the same but it need a bit more work, especially if you want to stop your headers wrapping.  There's a good introduction to grid from [Kevin Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU) and [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) also have a good guide. It's very powerful and recommended to learn both flex and grid as they solve a lot of problems from the bad old days.

```css
.indent-1 {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="indent-1">
  <section>
    <h3>What we like:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Pro 1</li>
      <li>Pro 2</li>
      <li>Pro 3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>What we don't like:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Con 1</li>
      <li>Con 2</li>
      <li>Con 3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.indent-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid orangered;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="indent-1">
  <section>
    <h3>What we like:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Pro 1</li>
      <li>Pro 2</li>
      <li>Pro 3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>What we don't like:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Con 1</li>
      <li>Con 2</li>
      <li>Con 3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the gap between the two?

Comment: @SulemanElahi sure, you can remove justify-content: space-between; from indent1 style ... instead add margins for section eg: section {margin: 10px; }